# Django - Adding password validations in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have made a ModelForm in Django for the registration of a new user. It has 4 fields (`username`, `email`, `password`, and `confirm_password`). I want to add some validations for the `password` field. For example, if the password is shorter than 8 characters or the password is similar to the username, then raise an error message. How can I do this?

Here is my `forms.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class user_form(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email', 'password','confirm_password']
```

My `settings.py` already contains the following validators:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimila‌​rityValidator', 
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValida‌​tor',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValid‌​ator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordVali‌​dator',
    }
]
```

It's already in `settings.py`, but my form's password is not being validated.

Comment: Did you tried overriding password clean method ?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @Hashir Sarwar I updated my answer to explain how to trigger the password validation when validating a form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to read the Django documentation about [Password Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation).

To summarize, you'll need to update the `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` setting in your `settings.py`.

Django comes with a few built-in password validators:

1. `UserAttributeSimilarityValidator` (checks for similarity between the password and a set of attributes of the user)
2. `MinimumLengthValidator` (checks whether the password meets a minimum length)
3. `CommonPasswordValidator` (checks whether the password occurs in a list of common passwords)
4. `NumericPasswordValidator` (checks whether the password isn’t entirely numeric)

Based on the example validations you state in your question, you'll want to use the `MinimumLengthValidator` and the `UserAttributeSimilarityValidator`.

Since you are using a form, you need to manually trigger the password validation as described in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#integrating-validation)) by calling `django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password` when you validate the form.

Comment: I have to add these functions in views.py?

Comment: Wherever you are validating your form, you need to do the following
1. Import `django.contrib.auth.password_validation`
2. Call `validate_password`

If you edit your question to show where you are doing form validation, I can help show you where to add the call to `validate_password`.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation. :)

Comment: `validate_password()` is only checking whether the password is 8 character long. How can I check the other factors like `CommonPasswordValidator` and `NumericPasswordValidator` ?

Comment: @HashirSarwar I'd be happy to help if you write a new question containing the details of the new problem. Please share the link here if you do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844780/django-password-validation-in-modelforms

Answer (score 5):

in forms.py file you can use this to validate the password for all validations which have been defined in settings. if you didn't define any of the validators in the settings file then  call a specific validator which you want to validate.

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password`
from django.core import validators
from django import forms
class User_profileForm(forms.ModelForm):
password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,validators=[validate_password])
```